# Mixing Razor and JavaScript

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm trying to use an anchor tag within a webgrid to call a javascript function. I can't get the syntax right. This is as close as I've come:

```
gridSpecs.Column(header: "", columnName: "", format: (item) => @:<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="DoSomeWork(@item.EquipmentId);">x</a>),
```

However, the VS IDE still complains about a missing parenthesis. I've tried wrapping the anchor tag with `<text></text>`. I've also tried it without the `a:` and with the `a:` (above).

How am I supposed to be able to use an anchor to call my javascript method?

I've even tried Html.ActionLink(), but that makes a call to the server, and I don't want to do that:

```
@Html.ActionLink("x", null, new { id = item.Id }, new { onlick = "DoSomeWork();" })
```

If it helps, here is the entire webgrid HTML:

```
<div class="webgrid-wrapper">
    <div id="grid">
        @gridSpecs.GetHtml(
            tableStyle: "webgrid",
            headerStyle: "webgrid-header",
            footerStyle: "webgrid-footer",
            alternatingRowStyle: "webgrid-alternating-rows",
            columns: gridSpecs.Columns(
                gridSpecs.Column(header: "", columnName: "", format: (item) => @:<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="DoSomeWork(@item.EquipmentId);">x</a>),
                gridSpecs.Column("Equipment.EquipmentId", "ID"),
                gridSpecs.Column("Equipment.Name", "Name"),
                gridSpecs.Column("Equipment.LegacyEquipmentId", "Legacy ID")))
    </div>
</div>
```

**This is the line that finally worked:**

(Hope this helps save someone else two hours...)

```
gridSpecs.Column(header: "", columnName: "",
    format: (spec) => MvcHtmlString.Create(string.Format("<a href='' onclick='DoSomeWork({0}); return false;'>x</a>", spec.Equipment.EquipmentId))),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suspect the line should be:

```
gridSpecs.Column(header: "", columnName: "", format: (item) => string.Format("<a href=\"\" onclick=\"DoSomeWork({0}); return false;\">x</a>", item.EquipmentId)),
```

Your approach didn't work because the line is .net code, and already in razor context. You only use `@:` or `<text>` to break out of Razor context (i.e. write out the rest of the line to the Response), which isn't appropriate here.

Sorry for tinkering with your logic but I consider it best practise to use `string.Format` for string interpolation, and to avoid the use of javascript in `href` attributes.

**UPDATE v2** (v1 was no good :)

I've not used WebGrid so I didn't realize that it escapes HTML sent to the `format` property. Can you try this:

```
gridSpecs.Column(header: "", columnName: "", format: (item) => MvcHtmlString.Create(string.Format("<a href=\"\" onclick=\"DoSomeWork({0}); return false;\">x</a>", item.EquipmentId))),
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is what I see on the web page when I try that: `<a href="" onclick="DoSomeWork(5); return false;">x</a>`. (I actually see the HTML on the page.)

Comment: I just tried the update and now I get this: `Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'object' because it is not a delegate type`

Comment: If it helps at all, I posted my latest attempt, and the results, in the question.

Comment: Sorry, that'll teach me to trust other posts on SO ;) Can you try my v2 update :) Let's see if WebGrid honours a `MvcHtmlString`

Comment: It worked! Woo hoo! I think I'm coming up on two hours now with this problem. Thank you for sticking with me on this!

Comment: By the way, within string.Format() I used single quotes instead of double quotes. That way I didn't have to use the ugliness of escaping the quotes.

Comment: Interesting, I had always assumed that single quotes weren't valid attribute delimiters in XHTML - turns out I'm wrong. I'm going to carry on using double-quotes though, because I strictly use single quotes for my javascript string literals, and I'll get really confused if I change now :)